# Fetch Configuration File from Network Device using SNMP by Zabbix

Tags: snmp, zabbix

I am connected via zabbix to network devices e.g. Routers, FWs etc. via **SNMP** and we can monitor resources such as interfaces, CPUs etc.

Now I need to fetch the configuration file of these devices via the same protocol (SNMP). Can anyone help how to accomplish that!

I have found this article which shows that it is possible, but i don't know how to implement it

https://community.cisco.com/t5/network-management/using-snmp-for-fetching-running-config/td-p/1035527

Comment: Network administration questions belong to ServerFault. You need to reveal why it appears here.

Comment: where they appear! I didn't understand, and i am rarely posting on stackOverflow, so pardon me for any mistakes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Che CISCO-CONFIG-COPY-MIB you linked shows how to implement a snmp+tftp implementation, but IMHO it's not the way to go.

Zabbix is a monitoring platform, not a network management: you should use a different solution.

You should use something like [Rancid](https://www.shrubbery.net/rancid/) or a commercial solution like [Solarwind](https://documentation.solarwinds.com/en/success_center/ncm/content/getting-started/ncm-gs-backup-a-config-manually.htm#:%7E:text=Back%20up%20network%20configs%20with%20NCM%201%20Use,configs%20on%20all%20devices%20are%20backed%20up%20).

Comment: What do you mean by IMHO please, and are you thinking it is not possible to fetch file by SNMP alone

Comment: But as i am able to retrive interfaces status and many things using SNMP why not to retrive files or config via SNMP?

Comment: IMHO stands for “in my humble opinion”.
SNMP is used (mostly) for monitoring by retrieving objects (values by oid, like inoctets of an interface), while config files are universally transferred via ftp/tftp/scp/https : different tasks, different protocols, different suites of tools.

Comment: I am accepting your answer as the correct one, but is there an OID for running or startup configuration of network elements for all vendors! BTW, we are using Huauwei devices.